# Compare 2 Tables and listing results that are different but for all records affected and no nulls

Tags: sql, teradata

I have two tables, one is a master table that shows what each Combined(Unique Identifier) should have for each column value, the other table list each Combined and their current columns values. I am trying to compare the two tables and show each record that does not match the master table and what it should be. I am currently getting Nulls when the data does match, but I would like the data from the master table to populate. The issue is that when I do get the data from the master table to populate for the nulls it shows all the records, I would only like the records that have at least one mis-match to show and not all records. The example code is:

```
select a.combined, B.ID,B.code,

case
when A.CODE<>B.CODE
then A.CODE
End AS UPDATED_CODE,

B.QTY,
case
when A.QTY<>B.QTY
Then A.QTY
End AS UPDATED_QTY


FROM TABLE1 A
JOIN TABLE2 B ON A.COMBINED = B.COMBINED

where UPDATED_CODE is not null
or UPDATED_QTY is not null
```

This will show me the results needed but will give Nulls when the data does match. I will like it to show these results but also give the data from TABLE1 if there is a null. The example output from the query above is:

```
    Combined        ID      B.CODE UPDATED_CODE B.QTY   A.QTY
1   1234565646464   1212121 RTD    JOR          15      ?
2   5632232356565   3333333 JOR    SBB          15      ?
3   3253265899656   2222222 SBB    SIH          15      ?
4   2332359654151   1111111 SBB    RTD          15      ?
5   2124184324324   0000000 JOR    RTD          15      ?
6   1654653235466   4444444 JOR    RTD          15      ?
7   4323656235659   7777777 RTD    ?            0       15
```

Comment: If you don't want to return row with matching data you should change your condition to `WHERE A.CODE<>B.CODE OR A.QTY<>B.QTY` and add an `ELSE A.col` to each `CASE`

Comment: This worked perfect! It wont allow me to select your comment as the answer however.

Comment: You can't accept a comment as answer, so I posted this as an answer :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to return rows with matching data you should change your condition to `WHERE A.CODE<>B.CODE OR A.QTY<>B.QTY` and add an `ELSE B.col` to each `CASE`:

```
select a.combined, B.ID,B.code,

case
when A.CODE<>B.CODE
then A.CODE
else B.CODE
End AS UPDATED_CODE,

B.QTY,
case
when A.QTY<>B.QTY
Then A.QTY
else B.QTY
End AS UPDATED_QTY  

FROM TABLE1 A
JOIN TABLE2 B ON A.COMBINED = B.COMBINED

where A.CODE<>B.CODE
   or A.QTY<>B.QTY
```